# PostgreSQL - aborting after conditional insert

Tags: postgresql

If I have a conditional insert as part of a transaction. Further on in the transaction I need to insert some unrelated data, but I want to abort this if the conditional insert doesn't actually affect any rows.

```
INSERT INTO TicketBookings(BookingId, ConcertId, NumSeats) SELECT 1, 1, 5 WHERE (SELECT AvailSeats FROM Concerts WHERE ConcertId = 1) >= 5;
```

Regardless of whether this inserts a row or not (it won't if 5 seats aren't available) it is still a "successful" query. Further on in the transaction is an INSERT for some unrelated data, so (as I understand it) I can't use a trigger or a foreign key as it won't get passed the unrelated data I need.

What I want to do is to get the number of rows affected by my conditional insert and abort / rollback the transaction if it's 0.

Is there any way?

Thanks :-)

Comment: you need plpgsql for raising exception I believe, unless.

Comment: Youcould use a check constraint `availableseats >= 0` for the column definition. (and update that in a two table transaction)

Comment: Yes, Postgres will report the number of affected rows to the client in response to the `INSERT`. How you access this information depends on which client library you're using to run the query. In `libpq`, you get it from [`PQcmdTuples()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-exec.html#LIBPQ-PQCMDTUPLES). Take a look at the docs for your client library to find out how they expose it. (If the `execute()` function you're calling returns an integer, that's probably it.)

Answer (score 0):

One solution to trigger exception when no rows inserted, divide by zero.

**one row inserted, OK**:

```
BEGIN
Time: 0.087 ms
t=#  with i as (insert into s100 (rec_time) select 0 where true returning 1 as c) select 2/count(1) from i;
 ?column?
----------
        2
(1 row)

Time: 0.266 ms
t=# end;
COMMIT
Time: 1.651 ms
```

**zero rows will abort transaction:**

```
BEGIN
Time: 0.082 ms
t=# with i as (insert into s100 (rec_time) select 0 where false returning 1 as c) select 2/count(1) from i;
ERROR:  division by zero
Time: 0.276 ms
t=# end;
ROLLBACK
Time: 0.178 ms
```